# Validation rule for file upload in update Scenario

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I have file upload option in form. I have added field in model and added vlaidation rules as below.

```
[['file1'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'pdf,png,jpg', 'maxSize' => "10485760", 'tooBig' => "Maximum upload file size is 10MB"]
```

In edit mode, file field is not required. So I need to skip required field validation for update scenario but if user choose a file in update form, then extension, size need to be validated.

I changed rule as below.

```
[['file1'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'pdf,png,jpg', 'maxSize' => "10485760", 'tooBig' => "Maximum upload file size is 10MB", "on" => ["insert"]], 

[['file1'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'pdf,png,jpg', 'maxSize' => "10485760", 'tooBig' => "Maximum upload file size is 10MB", "on" => ["update"]],
```

But it is still asking upload a file in edit form.

Thanks

Comment: show respective action of controller.

Answer (score 0):

try below rules

```
[['file1'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'pdf,png,jpg', 'maxSize' => "10485760", 'tooBig' => "Maximum upload file size is 10MB"],
[['file1'], 'required', 'on' => 'insert'],
```

add scenario in your create action not in update

```
$model->scenario = 'insert';
```

Comment: It is not working. It is allowing empty file on insert mode. I have set 'insert' instead of 'file-create'

Comment: I have same code as yours except `$model->scenario = 'insert';` as it is not required to mention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115845/discussion-between-vishu-and-kumar-v).